# Notepad++ auto indention after opening curly bracket

Tags: notepad++, brackets

So what I would like to get is this :

```
public function someFunc()
{
    //start typing from here
}
```

after I type opening curly bracket and press enter, I want notepad++ to make a new line and indent it by one tab, and then close the curly brace in next line after it, something like netbeans have.

I am using XBrackets Lite plugin for autocompleteing brackets, but that plugin does not provide auto indention in new line, it just close the brackets on the same line like this :

```
public function someFunc()
{
}
```

I need this behavior for both php and javascript.

Can some one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! The `Notepad#` has such a feature, try this plugin out.

---

[OFF]

Another hint: try `WebEdit` plugin, too. You can create your own word list (Plugins > WebEdit > Edit Config) to boost up your work. *(It is recommended to comment out the default values of `[Commands]`, `[Toolbar]` and `[Tags]`, like `;1=a.bmp`).* Some ideas:

```
p=public function |() {\n\i\n}
r=require("|.php");
io=include_once("|.php");
l=console.log(|);
etc.
```

Comment: Is the link broken? Because I don't see a link to the plugin :p

Comment: @MagicLegend You should install it via Plugin Manager (Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager)

Comment: Well, I just gave up on notepad++ and opened Visual Studio xD Worked great btw ;-)

Comment: @MagicLegend Good job! Btw I collected some (useful) keywords for WebEdit users: http://pastebin.com/iTZZGLfa

Comment: Could you please edit your answer in a way that actually answers the question? Don't reply to comments. Just edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

JSTool plugin does that.

In order to install it, go to menu: Plugins - Plugins Admin...
Then mark JSTool to install and install it.

After installation go to menu: Plugins - JSTools - JSFormat (Ctrl+Alt+M)
and the text should be reformatted.

Answer (score 1):

If a proper language is selected - not plain text - the "Auto-indent" in Notepad++ works:

```
Settings - Preferences - Auto-Completion -> Auto-indent
```